# having trouble with global variable

Tags: c#

I looked all over the internet for solutions to this but none of them work:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Console.Write ("What is your name: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine ();

    sayHi ();
}

public static string sayHi() {
    Console.WriteLine ("Hello {0}!", input);
}
```

I don't need an answer that will help me do this without a global variable, that's not what I'm looking for

When I execute this I get this error:

```
The name 'input' does not exist in the current context
```

I tried making one of the lines

```
public string input = Console.ReadLine ();
```

but I get

```
Unexpected symbol 'public'
```

I tried

```
static string input = Console.ReadLine ();
```

But I get

```
Unexpected symbol 'static'
```

This

```
public static string input = Console.ReadLine ();
```

gives me

```
Unexpected symbol 'public'
```

I don't want a solution that doesn't use global variables

Comment: In C# everything MUST be in a class. When you want a global variable you can construct "static class Global { public string input; }" And you will access this as "Global.input" in your code.

Comment: I think you need to study the basic syntax of C# and concept of OO first, it will a lot better for your future coding

Comment: Needing global variables sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as global variables in C#. This will do the trick for you. You could also try the static class with static members solution to simulate something like global variables, but that still won't be a global variable.

Try this (you're using an attribute in the class in this solution, it will be "global" inside this class)

```
public class YourClass{

    private static string _input;

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write ("What is your name: ");
        _input = Console.ReadLine ();

        sayHi ();
    }

    public static string sayHi() {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello {0}!", _input);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a global variable.

Comment: @Rawling There is no such thing as global variables in C#. This will do the trick for him. He could also try the static class class with static members to simulate it, but it still won't be a global variable.

Comment: Then that's the answer to the question.

Comment: @Rawling Then post your answer instead of being needlessly pedantic because someone used the wrong terminology.

Comment: @Rob Why do you assume the asker "used the wrong terminology" and really wanted a class variable, rather than just being unaware that C# doesn't have global variables?

Answer (score 4):

You should declare the variable outside of the `Main` method in the class containing both functions:

```
private static string input;

public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Console.Write ("What is your name: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine ();

    sayHi ();
}

public static string sayHi() {
    Console.WriteLine ("Hello {0}!", input);
}
```

In this case the scope of the `input` variable will be the containing class and you can access it from all methods within this class.

Comment: This isn't a global variable.

Comment: It is global for the containing class. So it all depends on what your definition of global variable is.

Comment: @Rawling Since C# does not have global variables, and judging by the fact OP appears to be new to C#, I'd suppose this is as close as you're going to get - and what OP is looking for.

Comment: maybe also add how it should be done? tell him about passing parameters which is a much cleaner way of doing things.

Comment: The definition of global is "global". As in, everything can access and use it. There's no such thing as "global for the containing class", as that scope would be "class-level".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Static` class

```
static class Global
{
   private static string _gVariable1 = "";

   public static string Variable1
   {
      get { return _gVariable1 ; }
      set { _gVariable1 = value; }
   }
}
```

And you can use it like

```
Global.Variable1 = "any string value"
```